# Support version number and class name for route url with Azure Function 2.x

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

Route is defined with `v1` hard-coded like below :

```
    [FunctionName("Car")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Car(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/Car")]
    HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {

    }
```

Is it possible to change `v1` above like below with ASP.NET Core 2.x, where verion number is defined centrally and less error prone?

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CarController : Controller
{

}
```

Visual studio 2017

**Update**

I have two functions under a class with urls like this:

```
/v1/classname/car1

/v1/classname/car2
```

Currently, I have to do

```
Route = "classname/car1"
Route = "classname/car2"
```

Is it possible to centralise classname in the url part?

Is it possible to apply version number to functions under selected class. So that different version number can be used for functions of different class at the same time

I wonder if Azure Functions supports this like ASP.NET CORE 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description you provided, you want the verion number to be defined centrally. If so, you could use `routePrefix` in `host.json` to achieve it.

For v2, you could use the example in `host.json` as below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "v1"
    }
  }
}
```

And the Function header as following:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Car(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "Car")]
    HttpRequest httpRequest, ILogger log)
    {    }
```

The result is here:

```
[POST] http://localhost:7071/v1/Car
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http).

Comment: Your advice works perfectly. Can you please see my update for a similar issue?

Comment: The problem is that routePrefix applies to all endpoints. Is it possible to apply it to functions under selected class. So that different version number can be used for different functions at the same time.

Comment: It seems that it's possible. **The `routeprefix` that applies to all routes.** If you still want to apply route to selected class you could deploy function to azure and set `route` property in each function's `function.json`. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint).

Comment: Thx. Changing it on every function.json after publishing the code is error prone.  I wonder if Azure Functions supports this like ASP.NET CORE 2.x.

Comment: Why do you want Azure function support the same like asp.net core 2.x?